# Can't add file to git for no apparent reason

Tags: git, gitignore, git-add

I have this file under assets/fonts/myFont.otf

I can't check it into my repo. But it is not ignored as far as I can tell.

```
git checkout assets/fonts/myFont.otf
error: pathspec 'assets/fonts/myFont.otf' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

But adding it has no effect.

```
git add assets/fonts/myFont.otf
```

I can't get `git status` to show the file in any way.

I have tried so far:

- git add -f
- git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
- git config --global core.excludesfile
- checking all .gitignore files in the project
- Changeing the file ending from `.otf` to `.ttf` -> **It works**
- Moving /assets/fonts/* to . -> **It works**
- git check-ignore assets/fonts/* -> empty output

I could not find out why `*.otf` files are ignored in my `assets/fonts/` folder. Any other things that I can try to find out? Any Ideas what might cause this? OS is macos 13.14.6

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] for reproducing this issue? What does `git status` say?

Comment: the repo is quite big. I went through all .gitignore files and couldn't find a rule that would cause this. Shouldn't `git check-ignore` find those files? See edit, git status does not list those files, unless i change their ending or move them

Comment: What about `git status --ignored --untracked-files` ?

Comment: the folder shows up with the file that is supposed to be ignored: `assets/fonts/.DS_Store`. `myFont.otf` does not show up

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a new repo in isolation? What about on a different OS? What if you reset global or per-user git settings to their default?

Comment: MacOS file systems are case-folding by default. Perhaps the *committed* file is spelled differently, e.g., `assets/fonts/MYFONT.OTF` or `assets/FONTS/myFont.otf`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. 
The best solution was to copy folder, then you can clone the project, copy your new files into the cloned folder.

Force (-f) normally should add even ignored one.

Another solution was to remove the .git folder if I good remember.

(can't add a comment...sorry)

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was found with the help of toreks hint.

Apparently MacOS file systems are case-folding by default.

So after removing the folder `assets/fonts`, I saw in `git status`, that the file was checked into git with a different capitalization:

```
deleted:     assets/fonts/MyFont.otf
```

So after I added that deletion to my staging area, everything worked and was registered as would be expected. I would still say git should handle this differently.

Answer (score 1):

My issue is that a folder above my project has a '.gitignore' file that was affecting my current folder.